# Deleting the values on account based on the related object

Tags: soql

I have a custom object whenever a record is created it will update a custom_field__c value on Account. As a business request deleted some of the custom object records now they want to delete the value of the field on Account. How to do this ?Is trigger only the way? There are very few records with the values on account how to get the Ids of accounts to manually delete them?

Custom object have a lookup to Account.

Comment: You could do this with the new Process Builder without needing to write a trigger. Visit Trailhead to learn more about how to use it.

Comment: @crmprogdev - ProcessBuilder doesn't (?) have a triggering event on deletion of an sobject

Comment: Can I query  on Accounts to find the account ids where custom_field!=Null and custom_object=Null for that Account Id?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to write a query like that. @crop1645 I may have misread the question. In any case, I didn't stop to think that there wasn't an option to fire on delete in Process Builder. Have to wonder if a flow would do the job. For his "catch up" purposes, he should be able to write a query to ID the records, then delete the fields on those records using Dev Console.

Comment: query will need to be an anti-join: select id, name from account where fld__c != null and id not IN (select account__c from customObj__c)`